# Remove all routes from a map with mapbox

Tags: javascript, api, routes, mapbox

I have code with a structure similar to this one that I put in Codepen and I want to create a function to remove all the routes drawn on the map. But I can't remove the route in blue, which is the last one tested by mapbox.

codepen: https://codepen.io/lucasthaynan/pen/ZEqGYqM

Script done but unable to remove the route in blue:

```
function removeRoutes(map) {

  if (map.getSource("theRoute")) {
    map.removeLayer("theRoute");
    map.removeSource("theRoute");
  }
  if (map.getSource("theBox")) {
    map.removeLayer("theBox");
    map.removeSource("theBox");
  }
  if (map.getSource("clearances")) {
    map.removeLayer("clearances");
    map.removeSource("clearances");
  }
  if (map.getSource("route")) {
    map.removeLayer("route");
    map.removeSource("route");
  }
  if (map.getSource("load")) {
    map.removeLayer("load");
    map.removeSource("load");
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `directions.removeRoutes()` instead of removing the layers one by one? https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#removeroutes